# SQL how to split string after delimiter

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm creating a query in SSMS and we're using Server 2012 I believe.  I have about a month of SQL experience so I'm very new to this.

I have an alphanumeric string that I'm trying to split so I can have a column with just the numbers.  The string starts with 2-4 numbers, may or may not contain '|' as a delimiter, and has 3-4 characters at the end.

What can I do to separate the columns like this?

```
Current     Numbers   Everything else
461|CNC     461       |CNC
1147|CNC    1147      |CNC
1103FCR     1103      FCR
```

Current Code

```
SELECT
    a.CTI_EMP_ID,
    a.DS_LOAD_DT,
    a.DURATIONSEC,
    a.LGCY_SPSR_ID,
    a.MSG_TYPE_CD,
    a.SPSR_CLS_NM
FROM DW_RawData_CTIDetail a
LEFT JOIN DW_Dim_AssociateMapping b 
    ON a.CTI_EMP_ID = b.CTI_ID AND a.DS_LOAD_DT = b.ScheduleDate
WHERE 
    b.MUID = '400'
    AND a.DS_LOAD_DT >= '2019-08-01'
ORDER BY DS_LOAD_DT DESC
```

Comment: Create a regular expression that returns the index of the first non-digit. Than take the `LEFT` string up till that index. Try this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5549/using-regular-expressions-to-manipulate-text-in-sql-server-management-studio-2017/

Comment: I strongly suggest that you show the two columns you want as the result and include cases without "|".

Comment: @PM77-1 Good suggestion.  I made both edits to my post.

Comment: @RobertKock Maybe I missed it, isn't the link you posted just in regards to editing finding and editing text?  I can try to figure out how to create a regular expression if that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `patindex()` to locate the position of the last digit in the string, like:

```
patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', mycol)
```

Then you can use it in your query:

```
select 
    left(mycol, patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', mycol)) mydigits,
    right(mycol, len(mycol) - patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', mycol)) mychars
from t
```

**[Demo on SQLServer 2012 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ada66cd91fd5c0fb54bf33fa52742284)**:

```
with t as (
    select '461|CNC' mycol
    union all select '1147|CNC'
    union all select '1103FCR'
)
select 
    mycol,
    left(mycol, patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', mycol)) mydigits,
    right(mycol, len(mycol) - patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', mycol)) mychars
from t
GO
```

```
mycol    | mydigits | mychars
:------- | :------- | :------
461|CNC  | 461      | |CNC   
1147|CNC | 1147     | |CNC   
1103FCR  | 1103     | FCR
```

Comment: You missed "*may or may not contain '|' as a delimiter*" part. I believe full blown regex will be required.

Comment: The OP said that `may or may not contain '|' as a delimiter`. Your solution fails if it doesn't contain a delimiter.

Comment: @GMB Thanks for the quick response, but like the others reiterated not every string has the pipe character.

EDIT: Your updated solution doesn't work either.  If the string doesn't contain the pipe character it returns the entire string, numbers and characters.  Example, '1146FCR' returns '1146FCR'

Comment: @MyNameHere: yes, I did not notice in the first place because it was not showing in your sample data (although it was clearly stated in the text of your question!). My bad. See my updated answer that handles both cases.

Comment: OP wants to split letters from digits that can be separated by pipe.

Comment: Your updated solution doesn't work either. If the string doesn't contain the pipe character it returns the entire string, numbers and characters. Example, '1146FCR' returns '1146FCR'.

Comment: @MyNameHere: ok - I understood the question differently. Deleting this since it's not helpful, someone will most likely come up with a better suited solution, most likely using regexes, as suggested by PM77-1 (also, as suggested by him, you should probably edit your question to show sample data that is really representative of your use case).

Comment: @MyNameHere: gave a new shot at this after you edited your question. Hopefully this should be closer to what you ask for.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I thought I had explained it clearly.  I'll make sure to have better examples and be more explicit.  Your solution makes sense and it works.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome @MyNameHere! Apologies are from me, for not digging enough on your requirement... That was my most painful answer for the day :).